# How to display table structure based on what users registered

Tags: html, ajax, html-table, codeigniter-3

I am making a function where I track my users registration. The participants can choose whether they want to register at Red, Blue, Yellow, and Green. I have this table structure in my front end. (Please see the screenshot) My target is how can I do this output based on what registration color they chose? I'm getting confused around my code where I specify the table design should be. (Around $output). I hope someone can help. I'm a newbie. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you everyone.

[image: A screenshot of my target]

Controller: (I'm having a problem regarding   combination)

```
  function register()
{
    $data = $this->sample->register1();
    $prev = '';
    $next = '';


    $output = '<table style="margin-top: 5px;" id="display">';
    foreach ($data as $f) {


        $next = $f['registercolor'];


        switch ($f['registercolor']) {
            case RED:
                $btn = "bg-danger";
                break;
            case BLUE:
                $btn = "bg-primary";
                break;
            case GREEN:
                $btn = "bg-success";
                break;
            case YELLOW:
                $btn = "bg-warning";
                break;
            default:
                $btn = "bg-primary";
                break;
        }

        if ($prev === $next || $prev === '' || $next === YELLOW || $next === GREEN) {
             $prev = $next;
                $output .='<tr>';
        } else {
             $prevRegla = $nextRegla;
               
        }
$output .='<td h-align="top"><span data-toggle="tooltip" class="badge '.$btn.
            '" style="font-size: 1.6em; margin: .05em; border-radius: 30px;">'.$f['registerID'].'</span></td>';

    }
      $output .= ' </td></table>';
        
        echo json_encode($output);
}
```

https://prnt.sc/1m0owi3 << this is my current output

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, I fixed something in your source. Hope this help:

```
const RED = 'red',
    BLUE = 'blue',
    GREEN = 'green',
    YELLOW = 'yellow';

function register()
{
    $data = $this->sample->register1();
    $prev = '';
    $next = '';


    $output = '<table style="margin-top: -230px;" id="display">';
    foreach ($data as $f) {


        $next = $f['registercolor'];


        switch ($f['registercolor']) {
            case RED:
                $btn = "bg-danger";
                break;
            case BLUE:
                $btn = "bg-primary";
                break;
            case GREEN:
                $btn = "bg-success";
                break;
            case YELLOW:
                $btn = "bg-warning";
                break;
            default:
                $btn = "bg-primary";
                break;
        }

        if ($prev === $next || $prev === '' || $next === YELLOW || $next === GREEN) {
            $output .= '<td v-align="top"><span data-toggle="tooltip" class="badge ' . $btn .
                '" style="font-size: 1.6em; margin: .05em; border-radius: 30px;">&#664;</span></td>';
        } else {
            $output .= '</tr><tr><td v-align="top"><span data-toggle="tooltip" class="badge ' . $btn .
                '" style="font-size: 1.6em; margin: .05em; border-radius: 30px;">&#664;</span></td>';
        }
    }
    // prevent change from same color like this case : RED -> YELLOW -> RED
    if ($next !== YELLOW && $next !== GREEN) {
        $prev = $next;
    }
    $output += '</tr></table>';
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm trying it out. I'll update you. :D

Comment: Hi this is what happened https://prnt.sc/1m0owi3

I also edited my code above. :D

Comment: I am still looking for help. If you're available maybe you can lend a help. Thank you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73661995/how-to-display-table-data-structure-based-on-what-users-registered