# How to display table data structure based on what users registered

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am making a function where I track my users' registration. The users can choose whether they want to register at Red, Blue, Yellow, and Green. I have this table structure in my view. (Please see the screenshot) My target is how I can do this output based on their chosen registration color.

The first image is my target output.

The second image is my current output.

I have provided more explanation here with 3 conditions

```
if the previous color is the same as the current color, the data will go down.

example: 
prev - red
next - red 

the logs should go to the next column if the current color is not the same as the previous color

prev- red
next - blue


If the colors are Yellow And Green, the data will go down
```

Any suggestion/s on how can I achieve my target? Thank you

[image: Target output]

[image: Current Output]

Controller:

```
function transaction(){
    $data= $this->dashboards->queryTransaction();
    $res = array();
    $prev = '';
    $next = '';
    
    $output = '<table id="displayLogs" class="table-bordered" >';
    $current = 0;
    $res[$current] = array();
    
    foreach ($data as $f) {
        $next = $f['logs'];
        switch ($f['logs']) {
            case "red":
                $btn = "bg-danger";
                break;
            case "blue":
                $btn = "bg-primary";
                break;
            case "green":
                $btn = "bg-success";
                break;
            case "yellow":
                $btn = "bg-warning";
                break;
            default:
                $btn = "bg-primary";
                break;
        }
        
        if ($prev == $next || $prev == '' || $next == "yellow" || $next == "green") {
        } else {
            $current++;
            $res[$current] = array();
        }
        $res[$current][] = $btn;
        // prevent change from same color like this case : RED -> YELLOW -> RED
        if ($next != "yellow" && $next != "green") {
            $prev = $next;
        }
    }
    
    $max = count($res[0]);
    foreach ($res as $btn) {
        if (count($btn) > $max) {
            $max = count($btn);
        }
    }

    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {

   
        foreach ($res as $btn) {
            if (array_key_exists($i, $btn)) {
         
            
            
                $output .= '<td ><span data-toggle="tooltip" class="badge ' . $btn[$i] .
                '" style="font-size: 23px; margin: 0px; border-radius: 50px;">&#664;</span></td>';
            
            }else{
                $output .= '<td ></td>';
            }
      
        }
        $output .= '</tr>';
    }
    


    echo json_encode($output);
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're alternating between red and blue columns, yellow and green values are allowed in both columns. Values seem to be added from top to bottom and whenever a column can no longer add a value vertically, new values for that column are added to the right (making a 90 degree corner).

The last column in your example doesn't seem to follow this logic (I would end up with 37, 38, 39 and 40 in a horizontal row), so I've added some extra logic (the `if ($y === 0)` part) that adds values vertically again if the current value was added at the top of a new column.

```
$colors = ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue'];

$array = [];
$columnColor = null; // will be red or blue
$currentColumn = 0;
$x = 0;
$y = 0;

foreach ($colors as $key => $color) {
    
    // if the current color is red or blue
    if ($color === 'red' || $color === 'blue') {
        
        // and the current color is different from the columnColor
        if ($columnColor !== null && $columnColor !== $color) {
            $currentColumn++; // move the currentColumn to the right
            $x = $currentColumn; // restart x in the current column
            $y = 0; // restart y at the top of the column
        }
        
        // set the columnColor
        $columnColor = $color;
    }
    
    $number = $key + 1;
    $array[$x][$y] = "<span style='color:$color'>$number</span>"; // change this to your table cell contents
    
    // calculate the coordinates for the next value:
    
    // if the current value was added vertically, we haven't reached the 6th row yet
    // and the next value can also be added vertically
    if ($x === $currentColumn && $y + 1 < 6 && !isset($array[$x][$y + 1])) {
        // add the next value vertically
        $y++;
    // else (the current value was added horizontally, we've reached the 6th row,
    // or the next value can not be added vertically)
    } else {
        // add the next value horizontally
        $x++;
        
        // if we happen to have moved right into the first position of a new column
        if ($y === 0) {
            $currentColumn = $x; // set the currentColumn equal to x, so that new values are again added vertically
            $columnColor = null; // reset the columnColor
        }
    }
}
```

And the html:

```
<table>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) : ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($array as $x) : ?>
                <td><?php echo $x[$i] ?? ''; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: I will try it now. Thank you. Will keep you updated